# SQL hierarchical query 4 levels sum

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, hierarchical-data

I have hierarchycal table of Clients you now ID and parentID. there is also a column named depth, whitch represents their depth in hierarchy. For example Client1 has ID 1 and he is also on the top of hierarchy so he has depth 1. His child Client2 has ID 7 and depth 2. The depth is important coz I have query, where I want to select Clients unter their parent whos depth is max parentDepth + 4(limiting depth select). Now let's move to the prob. for every child in 4 levels the parent Client has some money. 250, 100, 50 and 25 based on their depth. I need to build query to select all clients and how much money I should pay to them.

The Client1 for exaple will have 250 in case he has no more Clients in his hierarchy. I spent all night solving this. Can you guys please help? The best option would be similar to this:

`ClientID | sum
5        | 550
6        | 400`

and so on.

the best I could make is :

```
SET @myDepth = 1;
SET @ID = 22;

Select Client.ID, sum from Client JOIN ( 
    select SUM(depthValue) as sum, ID from ( 
        select depth, validTo, ID from( select ID, owner, depth, validTo 
        from Client order by owner, ID) products_sorted, (SELECT @pv := @ID) 
        initialisation where find_in_set(owner, @pv) > 0 and 
        @pv := concat(@pv, ',', ID)) as Ty 
   INNER JOIN depthTable ON Ty.depth - @myDepth = depthTable.dep where 
   Ty.depth <= @myDepth + 5) as ano 
WHERE Client.ID = @ID
```

There is also used second table named depthTable which includes just 4 records and hasjust 2 columns: dep (1,2,3,4) and depthValue(250,100,50,25). I use it as enum. This code can select just one Client with predefined ID and his depth.
Plz help!

Comment: Using a simple linked list like "id, parentid" will give you troubles like this. MySQL is not able to do recursion yet, and a linked list requires that. Since you have a limited depth, you can however use 4 left joins to join all children, then to join their children and so on. If you'd like to look at a different approach to make a hierarchy, try e.g. [nested sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). The link also explains how to use the joins (which is fine to use if you know how deep your tree can be, although here, a nested set might actually be easier).

Comment: What is your table structure and some sample data?